# How to make pd.DataFrame print list values in cells as a proper python list?

Tags: python, pandas

```
> print(pd.DataFrame({'a': [['x', 'y']]}))

        a
0  [x, y]
```

Even though the DataFrame cell contains a list just as expected, when printed, it is represented as `[x, y]` instead of `['x', 'y']`. This happens even if I use `repr()`.

Can I tell pandas to print list values properly, e.g.:

```
        a
0  ["x", "y"]
```

And why does this happen anyway? Python has a convention that `repr` should be as close to reversible as possible (i.e., `ast.literal_eval(repr(x))` should work with minimal tweaks whenever possible). This behavior is quite confusing and makes debugging unrelated errors very tricky (I actually thought there was a bug in my code causing the list to be stored in the DataFrame as a string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to apply `formatters=[repr]` in the `to_string` method of a data frame, like this:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'a': [['x', 'y']]})
print(df.to_string(formatters=[repr]))
```

Another example:

[image]

---

p.s. The current default behavior is good enough in my opinion because it saves space by printing data more compactly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': [['x', 'y']]}
data['a'] = [repr(d) for d in data['a']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           a
0  ['x', 'y']
```

Comment: You're modifying the data, which is most likely not a good idea

Comment: @mozway Thanks for the headsup , i have modified the code